# JS create dont refresh content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

At my site I have a staff-list where each `staff` can be clicked. Upon click a jquery mobile popup is opened and load dynamic content using `AJAX`. Here the user may select to delete the selected staff. However, upon success delete I need to close the popup and refresh the staff-list. I thought that `.trigger("create")` would do this but apparently not.

JQuery code:

```
$("#dynform").on("click", ".delete_staff", function() {
  var delete_staff = $(this).attr("data");
  alert("Click is recorded");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "include/handler/delete.ajax.php?status=-1&type=" + delete_staff,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response).trigger("create");
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: `trigger('eventName')` triggers/fires the named event, and associated event-handler; what function are you using in response to that event? And, while I'm not sure, I don't think chaining `trigger()` to an `alert()` will do anything at all, do you have errors reported in your console?

Comment: You´re right `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined`
Actually what I'm after is to refresh the entire page content.

Comment: In which case please [edit] your question to clearly explain what you want to happen (provide relevant [mcve] code, and sample data to be returned by the server's response), and what the resulting  output should be. You've shown what you tried, but also include "what went wrong" (the error message, and undesired effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a severe error in your code at line 9.
See the example below:

```
$("#dynform").on("click", ".delete_staff", function() {
  var delete_staff = $(this).attr("data");
  alert("Click is recorded");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "include/handler/delete.ajax.php?status=-1&type=" + delete_staff,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
      //Let the variable "response" contain the new list, HTML-code generated by the server 
      //Let the element "dynform" be the list container
      //Let the element "myPopup" be the popup you need to close

      //Refresh list
      $("#dynform").html(response).listview( "refresh" );

      //Close popup
      $("#myPopup").popup("close");
    }
  });
})
```